# Which test to use to compare multiple choice answers for two groups of survey questions

Tags: chi-squared-test, survey

I have a situation where there are 200 scenarios presented in group A, and 200 scenarios presented in group B, and I have a small panel of 4 domain "experts" choose between 3 options for rating the scenarios. They also happen to be randomized to see half of the scenarios in each group, so all raters rate 100 from each group, and each scenario is rated by two different raters.

If I want to test the hypothesis that "scenarios in group A are more likely to be rated with choice 1 by the expert panel" or simply, "the expert ratings for scenarios in group A are differently distributed than in group B" , how would I go about doing that ?

Although I have a small group of expert raters, I'm considering the N=200 questions in each scenario to be the sample size...

Would it be right to set up a table which is two columns (scenario groups) x 3 rows (choices) with raw counts in each cell from the raters and do a chi-squared or fisher exact test ? In that case because of the multiple raters it would look like a larger sample size and that seems like cheating somehow ?